# BadSQLGrammarException -- where's the error?

Tags: sql

I am getting a BadSQLGrammarException, but I cannot see where the error is in the following SQL statement:

```
insert into comment(comment_date, name, comment) values '4/27/2013', 'Frank', 'Test';
```

Here is the description of my table.  (Yes, I am converting a date into a String.  There are probably better ways to do it with SQL, but that's not the question here.)

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| comment_date | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name         | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| comment      | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (fieldlist) VALUES (valueslist)
                                     ^--        ^--
```

you forgot the indicated brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Try using parentheses around the values, like this:

```
insert into comment(comment_date, name, comment) values ('4/27/2013', 'Frank', 'Test');
```